# A value of type 'Style' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML code. I want alternate lines in my listview which will be populated dynamically though the code at run time. 
I'm using the following XAML code but it give error called Error8   A value of type 'Style' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.

```
 <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" BorderBrush="#FFA8CC7B" Height="133" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,93" Name="lstViewAppsList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="596"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingStyle}" AlternationCount="2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Apps" Width="150" />
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Package" Width="350" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <Style x:Key="alternatingStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="BValue="LightSkyBlue"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: How to add it to the resource dictionary? Do I have to create a separate file?

Answer (score 6):

It needs to be in a `ResourceDictionary` of some sort, you can add to the `ListView` or the `Window/Page` resources or even an external resource file

```
<ListView.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="alternatingStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
       ......
   </Style>
<ListView.Resources>
```

So to add it to your example above

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" BorderBrush="#FFA8CC7B" Height="133" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,93" Name="lstViewAppsList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="596" AlternationCount="2">
    <ListView.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
           ......
       </Style>
    <ListView.Resources>
     <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn  Header="Apps" Width="150" />
             <GridViewColumn  Header="Package" Width="350" />
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: How do we add a resource dictionary?

Comment: added better example above

Comment: Is itemContainerStyle in the ListView property is correct? It shows the following error. Resource alternatingStyle could not be resolved.

Comment: You can either move the `Style` out a level to the `Window` or `Parent` element (again into `.Resources`), or you can remove `x:Key="alternatingStyle"` from the `Style` and `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingStyle}"` from the `ListView` and the style will be applied to the `ListView` as the `ListView` will look in its own Resources before looking elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

You need to place this style in ResourceDictionary. If you are using , Place the style as follows,

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="alternatingStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
</Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Regards,
Riyaj Ahamed I